# position all elements in one line

Tags: html, css

I have hard coded the css code below to put all the elements in one line.

I wonder if there is a better solution for this:

```css
.switch-container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: box;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -o-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -o-box-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -o-box-orient: vertical;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}
.switch input { 
    display:none;
}
.switch {
    display:inline-block;
    width:80px;
    height:25px;
    margin:5px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    -webkit-transform:translateY(50%);
    transform:translateY(50%);
    position:relative;
}

.slider {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    border-radius:20px;
    background: #B7B7B7;
    cursor:pointer;
    border:4px solid transparent;
    overflow:visible;
    -webkit-transition:.4s;
    transition:.4s;
}
.slider:before {
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    background:#ff003c;
    border-radius:100px;
    top: -8px;
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-10px);
    transform:translateX(-10px);
    -webkit-transition:.4s;
    transition:.4s;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}

.switch input:checked + .slider:before {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(50px);
    transform:translateX(50px);
    background:#4287f5;
}
.review {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    left: -190px;
    top: -13px;
    color: #ff003c;
    -webkit-transition: all ease .4s;
    transition: all ease .4s;
}
.study {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    right: -120px;
    top: -45px;
     color: #d3d3d3;
    -webkit-transition: all ease .4s;
    transition: all ease .4s;
}
.switch input:checked ~ .review {
    color: #d3d3d3;
}

.switch input:checked ~ .study {
    color: #4287f5;
}
```

```html
<div class="switch-container">
  <div>
    <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox">           
      <span class="slider"></span>
      <p class="review">Review Mode of Study</p>
      <p class="study">Study Mode of Learning</p>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the way your using the "checkbox hack" for the slider to become `checked` and then style the text based on it's checked state, the two `<p>` tags will have to be children of the `<label>` and siblings of the `<input>` for `.switch input:checked ~ .review` to work as expected for changing the `color` of each paragraph text when the slider is toggled from side to side. I added a class `.flex-row` which makes the `<label>` a flex container to keep everything aligned in a row. You were correct in using `position` to make the `<p>` tags move to the left/right so they aren't directly on top of the slider.

```css
.switch-container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: box;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -o-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -o-box-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -o-box-orient: vertical;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}
.switch input { 
    display:none;
}
.switch {
    width:80px;
    height:25px;
    margin:5px;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-left: 25px;
    -webkit-transform:translateY(50%);
    transform:translateY(50%);
    position:relative;
}

.flex-row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.slider {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    border-radius:20px;
    background: #B7B7B7;
    cursor:pointer;
    border:4px solid transparent;
    overflow:visible;
    -webkit-transition:.4s;
    transition:.4s;
    width: 80px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.slider:before {
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    background:#ff003c;
    border-radius:100px;
    top: -8px;
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-10px);
    transform:translateX(-10px);
    -webkit-transition:.4s;
    transition:.4s;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}

.switch input:checked + .slider:before {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(50px);
    transform:translateX(50px);
    background:#4287f5;
}

.review {
    color: #ff003c;
    -webkit-transition: all ease .4s;
    transition: all ease .4s;
    position: relative;
    left: -4rem;
}
.study {
    color: #d3d3d3;
    -webkit-transition: all ease .4s;
    transition: all ease .4s;
    position: relative;
    right: -6.5rem;
}

.switch input:checked ~ .review {
    color: #d3d3d3;
}

.switch input:checked ~ .study {
    color: #4287f5;
}
```

```html
<div class="switch-container">
  <div>
    <label class="switch flex-row">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span class="slider"></span>
      <p class="review">Review Mode of Study</p>
      <p class="study">Study Mode of Learning</p>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Option 2

This method will make the container responsive for all viewport sizes, where the first option (your current implementation) will overflow the viewport at smaller screen sizes.

If you were to use JavaScript to apply the color change for each paragraph element instead of the general sibiling combinator `~`, the row format would be much more straightforward and wouldn't require any re-positioning of the paragraph elements with `position`. I made the child `<div>` of `.switch-container` a Flexbox and utilized `justify-content: space-evenly` to position flex items evenly in the row.

Then I replaced `margin: 5px` on the `.switch` container with `margin: 5px 2rem` to provide appropriate left/right spacing between the text and slider. Also, the slider was a bit too far down on the y-axis with `transform:translateY(50%)` so I removed that transform as the Flexbox container aligns items in the row along the cross-axis (vertical axis) with `align-items: center`. Lastly, to handle the `<p>` tags changing color when the `<input>` is checked, just use a little bit of JavaScript to grab the elements from the DOM and change their `color` when the `<input>` is checked or not.

```js
const review = document.querySelector(".review");
const study = document.querySelector(".study");
const sliderInput = document.getElementById("slider-input");
const sliderSpan = document.querySelector(".slider");

function isChecked(element) {
  if (!element.checked) {
    study.style.color = "#4287f5";
    review.style.color = "#d3d3d3";
  } else {
    study.style.color = "#d3d3d3";
    review.style.color = "#ff003c";
  }
}

// attach click event listener to the <span> which is being clicked to toggle the input
sliderSpan.addEventListener("click", () => {
  isChecked(sliderInput);
});
```

```css
.switch-container {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.switch-container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: box;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -o-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -o-box-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -o-box-orient: vertical;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}
.switch input { 
    display:none;
}
.switch {
    width:80px;
    height:25px;
    margin: 5px 2rem;
    margin-left: 25px;
    position:relative;
}

.slider {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    border-radius:20px;
    background: #B7B7B7;
    cursor:pointer;
    border:4px solid transparent;
    overflow:visible;
    -webkit-transition:.4s;
    transition:.4s;
    width: 80px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.slider:before {
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    background:#ff003c;
    border-radius:100px;
    top: -8px;
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-10px);
    transform:translateX(-10px);
    -webkit-transition:.4s;
    transition:.4s;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}

.switch input:checked + .slider:before {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(50px);
    transform:translateX(50px);
    background:#4287f5;
}


.review {
    color: #ff003c;
    -webkit-transition: all ease .4s;
    transition: all ease .4s;
}
.study {
    color: #d3d3d3;
    -webkit-transition: all ease .4s;
    transition: all ease .4s;
}
```

```html
<div class="switch-container">
  <div class="row">
    <p class="review">Review Mode of Study</p>
    <label class="switch">
      <input id="slider-input" type="checkbox">
      <span class="slider"></span>
    </label>
    <p class="study">Study Mode of Learning</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @SaraRee Have a look at "Option 2" of my answer. I think that would be the best method in terms of creating something that's responsive and is viewable on all viewports. It might be a bit more work to make "Option 1" fully responsive, since the DOM structure must be a certain way for the general sibiling combinator to work as you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

i think its a relevant question.

You can use

```
display: flex;
```

wich will be inline.
Than you can define with:

```
justify-content:
```

and

```
align-items:
```

how the elements are placed.

If you want to learn more about it checkout: https://www.mediaevent.de/css/display-flex.html

Comment: A German website is not much use for readers of an English website, FWIW.